# How to deduce type of data while retriving from Hbase

Tags: hbase

I am exploring Hbase.
One of the problem i am facing is "How to convert value retrieved by Get from Hbase to specific Java data type".For e.g. i am storing 3 Strings , 1 Integer and 1 Float in Hbase.Everything gets converted to byte[] . So while looking up data , how do i know which is which ?
Please help here.

Answer (score 1):

HBase stores everything as bytes. It does not know/care what the bytes mean. This is the job of your application. You know what you stored there, so you know how to convert it back into the original format.

An automatic approach does not exist. You could implement something yourself though. For example by adding a prefix byte to your data. The first byte of your byte array would then determine the type of data that is stored in the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0):

OK..I got it..You need something readymade. check [this](https://github.com/junegunn/hbase-jruby) out. I hope you know some Ruby, so that you can tinker the Hbase shell as per your requirements the next time, as solution to each and every problem of yours might not be readily available.

HTH